# Messed up my vim colorscheme and can't get it back

Tags: vim, colors, terminal, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

So I had this beautifully themed Vim colorscheme which used the terminal colors (24bit true color Termite with dark solarized color theme), the visual mode simply reverted the colors in selected text, basically it matched with my whole system theme.

Today I was trying to install Lightline plugin for Vim and the guide said to add the following lines of code to `.vimrc`:

```
if !has('gui_running')
  set t_Co=256
endif
```

I was happy with the plugin but ever since I added those 3 lines of code into my .vimrc, my colorscheme vanished. I've since tried deleting the plugin, deleting those 3 lines of code from my .vimrc, setting every colorscheme available in the `/usr/share/vim/vim81/colors` directory and nothing seems to bring back my old colorscheme - which used the terminal colors (I've aleady tried setting the colorscheme to default, but I'm still getting weird colors that I didn't have before).

Comment: If your terminal supports truecolor, then dont set the amount of supported colors to 256. You should almost *never* need to set `t_Co`

Comment: Lightline wasn't working without these 3 lines of code, I followed the instructions on the official GitHub repo and it worked. However not in a way I wanted to and I just want my colorscheme back...

Comment: Did you do the `export TERM` stuff? Again, you generally don’t need to set that; it should be configured by your term emulator (then vim sets `t_Co` via a database based on TERM

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to manually set the ```$TERM``` variable to ```xterm-termite``` and ```xterm-color``` but to no avail. I think the problem lies somewhere in setting that ```t_Co``` variable to 256 colors and I can't "unset" it (I've tried setting it to different numbers like 0 and 88 and even deleting it from the ```.vimrc``` alltogether but nothing works).

Comment: Try deleting the viminfo file. Are you using sessions at all? Again, it should get set automatically. Try closing out your terminal emulator after removing the export TERM stuff, and opening a new terminal. Then, after ensuring the t_Co stuff is not present in your vimrc, open vim again.